# I have implemented function without using function key but not able to print the result

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, php-7

I have written one function, without using `function` keyword.
if age is above 15 take the value and push into one array. I have done that but i am not able print the result.Kindly any one help on this.

> my code

```
<script>
var age = ["14", "20", "25"];
const response = howMany(people) {
  let oldCitizen = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
   if (people[i] >=15) {
    oldCitizen.push(people[i]);
   }
  }
  return oldCitizen;
}
console.log(howMany(age));
</script>
```

> Getting Error

(index):3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' (at (index):3:34)

I know below code also will work, but i need without `function` keyword i wants to implements one function and print the result.

```
<script>
var age = ["14", "20", "25"];
function howMany(people) {
  let oldCitizen = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
   if (people[i] >=15) {
    oldCitizen.push(people[i]);
   }
  }
  return oldCitizen;
}
console.log(howMany(age));
</script>
```

> updated code

```
<script>
var age = ["14", "20", "25"];
const howMany = (people) => {
let oldCitizen = [];
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  if (people[i] >=15) {
  oldCitizen.push(people[i]);
  }
}
return oldCitizen;
}
//console.log(howMany(age));
</script>

<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">howMany(["14", "20", "25"]);</script>';
?>
```

Comment: You are looking for [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: `const howMany = (people) => { ... }`

Comment: @hhearts, if possible can you please update my code, i have tried but no luck

Comment: @mwl, Yes i have followed your suggestion console it is displaying, but how can i print the same result in PHP ?

Comment: I tried like this but nothing is displying and also no error`<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">howMany(["14", "20", "25"]);</script>';
?>`

Comment: If you ask for a PHP print function you can use echo: 
( https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php ) or print ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print )

Comment: Show us your code. Where's `howMany` function?

Comment: Can you please check my `updated code`

Comment: missing `console.log`:
`echo '<script type="text/javascript">console.log(howMany(["14", "20", "25"]));</script>';`

Comment: Console.log for printing result in JS console but i wants to print in PHP

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
var age = ["14", "20", "25"];
const response = (people) => {
  let oldCitizen = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
   if (people[i] >=15) {
    oldCitizen.push(people[i]);
   }
  }
  return oldCitizen;
}
console.log(response(age));
```

Comment: Console.log for printing result in JS console but i wants to print in PHP